# R - change column content with function to new content

Tags: r, dplyr

Alright my problem is, that I have a dataframe with a column with species names like this:

1. Genus1 species1
2. Genus1 species2
3. Genus2 species3

And I simply want to cut the genus names like this:

1. G. species1
2. G. species2
3. G. species3

My problem isn't the string manupilation. I'll just can't figure it out how to simply use my function that looks like this:

```
truncateGenusName <- function(x){
  genus <- str_sub(x, 1, 1) 
  posOfSpace <- str_locate(x, " ")[1] 
  epitheton <- str_sub(x, posOfSpace, str_length(x)) 
  paste0(genus, '. ', epitheton)
}
```

I was trying to call the function like this:
`mutate(data, species = replace (species, TRUE, truncateGenusName(species)))`

The problem with this call is that not a single string is passed to the function, but a list.

I guess my approach is way too complicated. Does maybe someone have a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `stringr`.

`separate` from the `tidyr` package is used to turn the `names` column into two new columns `genus` and `species`.

`str_trunc` from the `stringr` package truncates the strings in the `genus` column. Note that the default is to apply three ellipses indicating that the string has been truncated. Using `ellipsis = "."` overrides that default to show only 1 ellipse.

`paste` has a default `sep = " "`, so it is preferable over `paste0` in my opinion.

```r
library(tibble) # Used to create a reproducible example. 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

# create a reproducible example dataset using the tibble package. 

df <- tibble(
  names = c("Genus1 species1",
            "Genus1 species2",
            "Genus1 species3")
)


# code to format the names column. 

df %>% 
  separate(names, c("genus", "species"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(genus = str_trunc(genus, 2, ellipsis = ".")) %>% 
  mutate(
    genus_species = paste(genus, species)
  ) %>% 
  rename(names = genus_species) %>%
  select(names)

# output table

#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   names      
#>   <chr>      
#> 1 G. species1
#> 2 G. species2
#> 3 G. species3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Original table:**

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   names          
#>   <chr>          
#> 1 Genus1 species1
#> 2 Genus1 species2
#> 3 Genus1 species3
```

Comment: ok, well it is almost what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure if it is also working without creating new columns? I'll just want to reduce overhead and simply reuse the column

Comment: @basto - I've updated my solution. Depending on your production dataset, you may have to add `select(names, everything())`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-liner in base R:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
    Genus1 species1
    Genus1 species2
    Genus2 species3
")

dat$V3 <- paste0(gsub("(?<=^.{1}).*", "", dat$V1, perl = TRUE), ". ", dat$V2)

dat

#       V1       V2          V3
# 1 Genus1 species1 G. species1
# 2 Genus1 species2 G. species2
# 3 Genus2 species3 G. species3
```

**Since I had misinterpreted the OP, a new one-liner solution (still just base R):**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
    Genus1 species1
    Genus1 species2
    Genus2 species3
")

dat$V3 <- paste0(dat$V1, " ", dat$V2)
dat <- dat[, 3, drop = FALSE]
dat

#                V3
# 1 Genus1 species1
# 2 Genus1 species2
# 3 Genus2 species3

#One-liner below:
dat$V3 <- gsub("(?<=^.{1})[A-Za-z0-9]+(?= )", ".", dat$V3, perl = TRUE)

dat
#            V3
# 1 G. species1
# 2 G. species2
# 3 G. species3
```

Comment: I find it hard to read regex-expressions, that's why I try to avoid them and this solution wouldn't work if the name of the genus and species are in the same column, which is quite normal in biological data..

Comment: I presume I have misunderstood your post. I see that what I had assumed to be individual columns are actually space-separated strings in a single column. In light of this, please note the new solution edited into my answer here. Unfortunately, this still uses regular expressions, I am afraid.

Comment: yes, now it's solving the problem probably, but still I would prefer the answer without a regular expression. anyway, thank you very much for your help!